# javascript class that contains user input

Tags: javascript, class, registration, authentication

I i am new to javascript and i have to create a class for a page i have in my current project.

its basically a registration page with all the expected fields. first name, last name and all

that good stuff.

my question is how to i create this class so that whatever the user inputs into these textfields will be stored and be used later. my ultimate goal here is to have a user set up
there username and all that then be able to logon with that info that was created.

```
 important note: 
                this class assumes that the server is accepting everything so this is
                strictly a javascript question.
```

thanks for all your help

-PostSynaptic

Comment: You don't need a class for this. The info entered by the user will be present in your form. Why don't you just submit the form and let the server take care of doing the registration with the submitted data?

Comment: well all of this is eventually going to be compiled into a native iphone application which can be used offline. there are things that need to bounce back to and from the server but i want to be able to handle user info locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sneaking suspicion that you are trying to do something that you shouldn't. Can you explain the complete situation?

Anyways, here's some code that might work for you. First, define a class like this:

```
function user_info (userId,password){
 this.userId = userId;
 ths.password = password;
}
```

from the onClick handler of your login button do this:

```
var user = new user_info(document.getElementById('userId').value,document.getElementById('password').value);
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I just have a deadline and we didn't have a JS guy so I had to pick up the language in like a week.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just have a deadline and we didn't have a JS guy so I had to pick up the language in like a week. Let me try to rephrase this. I need a class that can hold the data the user types in. So I have a ui and the form set up for each field. First name last name whatever. So at that point I need to know how to crate the class that has that data so that I can reference it in a script that deals with validation of the log on. I think the main confusion is this should be dealt with on the server but in my case this is a mostly offline application

Comment: @Postsynaptic3433: OK. So doesn't the code I have given here solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does and I thank you very very much. I just thought I'd explain my situation to see if you had any other opinions. But at any rate your a lfe saver :)

Comment: thanks, sorry i didnt know thats what you where supposed to do. new to the site lol